# Find all paths from adjacency matrix

Tags: c, recursion, matrix

I'm don't know how exactly to solve this problem. I was given a graph with 12 nodes A-L. 17 edges connect them. I was told to find all paths from A to L. I can traverse a node multiple times but an edge only once. The output should print each path and the total number of paths.

For example, if only 1 path. Output should be:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKL
12
```

I was thinking a recursive depth-first search function should be able to solve that, but I just can't figure out a way to print every single path. For example, if my function finds a path ABDL and reaches the end L, it prints ABDL. It then goes back to D and tries to find another path, how can I make it print from A again on the next line?

Any input would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does the graph have cycles? Is it directed or undirected?

Comment: The graph has cycles and is undirected

Answer (score 0):

Either pass the information to the last node, so it can print what path it followed when it hits a dead-end, or pass followed paths back to the caller, so it can print the entire paths at the end.

Recursively calling child functions and passing data forward should be obvious... dare I say it, straightforward ;)

For doing it the other way around, make your recursive function accept lists of traversed nodes from its child calls -- the the list of traversed sub-paths as a return value.  At the end of the function, if you're a sub-call, return those along with any node paths visited by the function itself (appending to the beginning of the others, and appending single nodes to the list if no further depth-recursion was done for some nodes).

At the very end, when you're not a sub-call, you'll have a list of all paths traversed, in full.  Just print them out.

For example, let's say you want to explore the letters [AAA, ABA, ACA, ABC, ACC], and some paths are invalid (say, you're not allowed to traverse C after A):

def mypathsearch(path_traversed, current_letter, remaining_letters):
    """Takes a string of letters searched, a current_letter character, and an
    array of character arrays containing remaining letter combinations for each
    position"""

```
if can_traverse(path_traversed, current_letter):

    for next_letter in remaining_letters[0]:
        letters_after = remaining_letters[1:]

        sub_paths_searched = mypathsearch(
            path_traversed + current_letter, next_letter, letters_after
        )

else:
    # end of the line
    print_path_traversed(path_traversed)
```